# How to use different css for queryset objects?

Tags: html, css, django, templates

I have different styles of heading in a 5- column layout newspaper template. I want to apply different css to the title of each column. The queryset is the `{% block content %}`How can I iterate over the queryset objects and apply different css to each `{{ post.title }}` variable? Note: html truncated for brevity.

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="columns">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
    </div>                 
    <div class="column">
       <div class="head">
          <span class="headline hl1">May the Force be with you</span>
          <p><span class="headline hl2">Let go your conscious self and act on instinct</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that `{% cicle %}` will help you.

```
{% for o in some_list %}
    <div class="{% cycle 'class1' 'class2' 'class3' %}">
        ...
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

more about built-in template tags you could read
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle